# Dont know how to return value from bubble sort function

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, return, bubble-sort

```
double b_sort(sample &s){
    int swap;
    int i = 0;
    int size = s.get_data().size();
    vector <double> vec;
    for (i; i < size; i++){
        if (s.get_data().at(i) < s.get_data().at(i + 1){
            swap = s.get_data().at(i + 1);
            s.get_data().at(i + 1) = s.get_data().at(i);
            s.get_data().at(i) = swap;
        }
    }
    return //dont know what to return;
}
```

Im sorting a vector that is defined by the user using bubblesort. However I dont know how to return the sorted vector.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `vec` is not used, and the signature says it will return `double`, which generally makes no sense since you are updating `s` in place.

Comment: Since you only use `s.get_data()` and nothing else from `s`, why don't you change the signature to accept the vector directly? (Or even simply use `std::sort` instead...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't need, there is no need to return, you can have return type as `void`

```
void b_sort(sample &s){
..
}//return nothing
```

Comment: Ohhh yeaaah! I was in such a rush to meet a deadline i completey forgot about that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to return anything. You have passed the vector by reference using `&` so it is already being modified in memory.

Use `void` and you don't need to return a value

```
void b_sort(sample &s){

}
```